# Choosing Linux for open source development

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, redhat

I work on Windows XP platform and use Aptana Studio, MySQL for PHP development. I want to know which Linux edition and flavor would be appropriate for my development purposes?

Comment: This is a matter of "taste", everybody has a preferred distibution IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too would go for Ubuntu, for several reasons.

1. It has a regular/predictable
   release schedule which I find very
   helpful as I can plan ahead for upgrades.
2. It provides both [Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/desktopedition) and [Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition)
   Editions. Potentially allowing you
   to become more familiar with your
   deployment environment if you choose
   to use Ubuntu Server while
   developing using Ubuntu Desktop.
3. Great Documentation which can be
   found here [Ubuntu Desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/index.html) and
   here [Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/index.html) which should cover most of your needs.
4. Friendly and helpful [community
   forums](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/webforums).

I have been using Ubuntu as a Desktop and Server for quite a while now and have found it to be an excellent distribution combination that has certainly made my life easier.

Comment: THis doesn't really address any of RPK's requirements though. Does it have MySQL pre installed? Php? All you're saying is: it's a great distribution.

Answer (score 8):

There aren't big differences between the major distros as far as availability of development tools. Might as well go with Ubuntu. It has a huge community and momentum behind it.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is "almost any edition or flavor".  Because Aptana and/or Eclipse, not to mention other developer tools and MySQL and PHP, will run well on any good modern desktop Linux distribution.  But personally I use all of the above under Ubuntu and like it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For Development I use **Gentoo Linux**, it has pretty much all the tools you could ever want and more, and the latest and greatest version of your favorite programs and it's the one distro that has the more tools available from the package manager.

That said, it takes a while to get used to it. AND You need to do the installing "by hand", which often teaches you how to use Linux and how stuff works, BUT takes time!

I use Aptana on my Gentoo box for development (that and Eclipse PDT) so you'd feel at home. Gentoo comes handy when you need to install stuff for that amazing idea you have, but that is not that common. In Gentoo even the most bizzarre tools come in the package manager (Portage) that makes it a GREAT development environment.

[Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) is one of the most customizable Linux distributions there is.

Comment: After using Gentoo for more than 3 years, I am starting to believe it's actually a noob distro :). The first time i actually compiled a package from source was on a Debian distro. The first time i actually had to hack autotools was on a CentOS. Every time I have to install ruby or nginx/passenger on a Debian based distro, i have nightmares at night. And if I had a nickle for every time i forget to install development headers or aptitude reports >20 unmet dependencies... Once you get Gentoo up and running, it's the most no-fuss distribution out there.

Answer (score 1):

As RC says, this is a matter of taste...

never the less, I would choose the distro that people around me are using => so we could support each other.

in my case, that means Ubuntu ..

Answer (score 1):

I like Ubuntu a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I use Kubuntu *(ie, Ubuntu with KDE instead of Gnome -- mater of personal choice)* and it's OK for LAMP development : you can use Eclipse PDT (or Aptana, of course), you have MySQL available, ...

... But I suppose any kind of Linux distribution will do ; maybe you will not always have the latest versions of PHP/MySQL, but PHP 5.2.x should be available for most distributions, I suppose.

And, if necessary, you can compile what you need from the sources *(I sometimes do that for PHP, to get the most recent version, as Ubuntu only provides 5.2.x, and not 5.3.x)*